# GUI in Chrome Packaged app

Tags: javascript, python, user-interface, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am new to Chrome packaged apps and GUI. What type of Gui can I use in Chrome Packaged apps? Can I use Tkinter in Python? or should I use Javascript GUI? If yes then which one you think is the best one to be used since I need to draw canvas and upload images to alter the brightness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Just like web apps, packaged apps are written in HTML5, JavaScript,
>   and CSS.

[According to Google's own page on the subject,](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps.html) packaged apps just open up more API's to you. They do not let you execute native code or other scripting languages. Your GUI must be written using HTML5 and JavaScript. [HTML5 Boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate) and/or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) might help.